# Intermittent pushing of objects to array

Tags: javascript

I have a simple block of code that is not working as intended. The code parses one array of objects and creates a second with the cumulative sizes found in the former array. The code works excellent on some datasets, but fails on others. This is exceedingly odd as all of the datasets were generated using the same tool and have no differences in white space.

The point in which the program fails is pushing the newly created object to the array. On some datasets it pushes an empty object, while on others it properly pushes it. Example console logs for failure are:

Index.html:461 {name: "Chr15", size: 6397009}

Index.html:467 (24) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] length: 0

While logs for functional code:
461 {name: "Chr4", size: 28450051}

Index.html:467 (35) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]  0: {name: "NKLS02002208_1", size: 2922554}

```
var sizetracker=[];

Blocks.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var tempname=arrayItem.QueChr;
    var tempsize=parseInt(arrayItem.RefEnd)-parseInt(arrayItem.RefStart);
    var temptest=false;

    sizetracker.forEach(function (newarrayItem) {
        if(newarrayItem.name==tempname){
            newarrayItem.size=newarrayItem.size+tempsize;
            temptest=true;
        }
    });

    if (temptest==false) {
        var datapoint = {};
        datapoint.name=tempname;
        datapoint.size=tempsize;
        console.log(datapoint);
        sizetracker.push(datapoint);        
    }
});

console.log(sizetracker);
```

I have no idea at this point. There is no appreciable difference in inputs.

Comment: Could you make a functional JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet (Ctrl-M) to demonstrate with two example objects, one failing and one succeeding?

Comment: The iteration limit for a `.forEach()` call are established when the iteration begins. Elements you add to the array inside the callback will not be part of the "loop".

Comment: I'm not sure we can solve this without a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - the code looks OK to me, but I don't know what expected values are for anything in `Blocks` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in integers and strings. I converted the values to strings before adding them to the object. The push then worked. I don't know why this worked, but I am not pursuing the problem.